# Eclipse: Make CTRL+. and CTRL+, ignore warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Eclipse supports jumping to the next and previous code "problems" with these shortcuts:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> - next error / warning
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> - previous error / warning

Is it possible to skip warnings and jump only to the next / previous errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do that, you'll explicitly have to tell Eclipse to only move between errors (and not warnings) when you press the `next` or `previous` annotation command.

You can do this by toggling the items checked in the `Next/Previous Annotation dropdown` menu from the toolbar. Here is a snapshot of that

[image: Error Navigation]

Note that by default, the `Errors` and `Warnings` options will be checked. Just uncheck the `Warnings` and you're done.